# Error when using Generic as property type in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm having an issue when using a Generic as the type constraint on a property. Here is a very simple example:

```
import UIKit

class TSSignal<MessageType> {

    var message: MessageType?

    init() {
    }

}
```

In Xcode 6 Beta (6A215l) this will not compile. It fails with the following error at the bottom:

```
TSSignal.swift:13:9: error: unimplemented IR generation feature non-fixed class layout var message: MessageType? ^ LLVM ERROR: unimplemented IRGen feature! non-fixed class layout Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolc‌​hain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code
```

But, if I remove the line `var message: MessageType?` it will build fine. Any ideas? Thanks.

**Edit** - changed code and error to reflect current status of issue

**Edit** - related: [Swift compile error when subclassing NSObject and using generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161563/swift-compile-error-when-subclassing-nsobject-and-using-generics)

**Update (6/18/14)** - The issue still persists as of Xcode 6 - Beta 2

**Update (7/25/14)** - The issue still persists as of Xcode 6 - Beta 4 (thanks @Ralfonso, and I verified as well)

**Update (8/4/14)** - The issue is FIXED as of Xcode 6 - Beta 5!

Comment: This code works just fine for me - sorry!

Comment: The problem apparently has to do with a `deinit`. Is there more of your code that you didn't show us? Was there a `deinit` and you took it out? (If so, clean out the DerivedData and try again.)

Comment: @Matt this is all the code. I'll clean out derived data and try again though, thanks.

Comment: it crashes playground immediately for me

Comment: Playground crashes if I breathe on it, so I wouldn't use that as a test. :)

Comment: Okay, forget cleaning out the derived data; I get exactly the same error, including the `deinit`.

Comment: @ColinE what is the build # for the Xcode you used to test?

Comment: @matt thanks for looking into this

Comment: I get exactly the same. file a bug report

Comment: I've filed a bug report, the ID is: 17293088

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161563/swift-compile-error-when-subclassing-nsobject-and-using-generics

Comment: Still a bug as of Xcode 6 beta 4

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround without type erasure (works as of Xcode6-Beta2):

```
import UIKit

class TSSignal<MessageType> {
    var _message: [MessageType] = []

    func getMessage() -> MessageType? {
        if _message.count > 0 {
            return _message[0]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func setMessage(maybeMessage: MessageType?) {
        if let message = maybeMessage {
            _message = [message]
        } else {
            _message = []
        }
    }

    init() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this workaround!! Still not working the way you'd expect...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT EDIT:

This is definitely a bug in the compiler.

I tried to 'outsmart' the compiler by using the following:

```
class TSSignal<TMessage>
{
    var messageType : Optional<TMessage> = nil

    init() { }
}
```

Same issue.

Comment: Doing this changed the error to this: TSSignal.swift:13:9: error: unimplemented IR generation feature non-fixed class layout
    var message: MessageType?
        ^
LLVM ERROR: unimplemented IRGen feature! non-fixed class layout
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 1

Comment: I'm confused by this because MessageType is not actually a real type. It's the name I'm giving to the generic. Are you saying that is the problem?

Comment: Sorry! I'm so used to seeing the `T` prefix that I wrongly assumed you were trying to use a defined type as the generic! Will revert my edit.

Comment: @BryanChen True, though it is still the answer from what it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT an "answer" (it is my own question), but I thought it worth noting what I did in this case to move passed this situation, for the time being.

```
import UIKit
class TSSignal {
    var message: AnyObject?
    init() {
    }
}
```

Lame, but I am sure it's only temporary.