# Swift - Can't convert BST node to generic

Tags: generics, swift

When implemented for a concrete type, my binary search tree node works fine in a playground:

```
class Node {
    var data: Int
    var leftChild: Node?
    var rightChild: Node?

    init(data: Int){
        self.data = data
    }
}

let n = Node(data: 42)      // {data 42 nil nil}
```

When I try to make it generic, Xcode crashes and burns:

```
class GenericNode<T: Comparable> {
    var data: T
    var leftChild: GenericNode?
    var rightChild: GenericNode?

    init(data: T){
        self.data = data
    }
}

let g = GenericNode<Int>(data: 42)
```

When entered line-by-line, Xcode survives until I enter the actual assignment in `init`.  I tried specifying `<AnyObject: Comparable>`, but apparently adding constraints to `AnyObject` is not allowed. How does one make suitably constrained generic containers in Swift?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193957/error-when-using-generic-as-property-type-in-swift

Comment: That seems to be fixed in Xcode 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely some bugs here. This code doesn't crash:

```
class GenericRootClass {
}

class GenericNode<T: GenericRootClass where T : Comparable> {

    let data: T
    var leftChild: GenericNode<T>?
    var rightChild: GenericNode<T>?

    init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

but as soon as I remove the GenericRootClass in the type constraint or change it to Any or AnyObject, Xcode crashes.

As an aside: you'll note a couple other changes in my code:

1. The `data` property should probably be immutable.
2. The child nodes should be of type `GenericNode<T>`, so that you can actually compare against their `data`. (The compiler would have pointed that one out, if it could survive long enough.)

Something as simple as

```
class GenericRootClass<T> {
    var data: T?
}
```

is able to crash Xcode 6 beta 2. It appears that generic classes aren't working at the moment.

Comment: Good catch on the declarations for the children `Node`s, thanks. In the long run I was going to make `data` immutable, but in the short run wanted to be able to play around with individual `Node`s in the playground. I don't see how a `GenericRootClass` helps solve the basic problem, though. Swift classes such as `Int` or `String` aren't subclasses of it, and I want a `Node` to be able to store _any_ payload which implements `Comparable` (including objects from classes that I haven't yet created).

Comment: Sorry, no, it doesn't solve the problem. It was just something I arrived at in testing to see what the scope of "things that will crash" was; this was evidence that constraining it the type parameter to a specific class hierarchy -- any class hierarchy -- works. I'd suggest substituting NSObject for it (while leaving the Comparable constraint in place) but it appears, at least for NSNumber, that Apple's bridging to Cocoa types does not extend to marking them as Comparable when they should be. It'd be simple enough to add that extension yourself, but you shouldn't HAVE to do any of this.

Comment: It's sad - I see a lot of potential for the language, but right now many things that should be simple soak up way too much time.

Comment: Since nobody has come up with an all-Swift solution, I'm marking your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more likely a bug. If you try to do this in `Swift` terminal, it will throw an error:

> LVM ERROR: unimplemented IRGen feature! non-fixed class layout

One workaround is to let `T` conform to `NSObject`.

Because `NSObject` is a protocol has required methods like [`isEqual()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a), which I think is kind of equivalent to an implementation of `Comparable`, **for now.**

So, the code would be like:

```
class GenericNode<T: NSObject> {
    var data: T
    var leftChild: GenericNode?
    var rightChild: GenericNode?

    init(data: T){
        self.data = data
    }
}

let g = GenericNode<NSNumber>(data: 42)
```

Then you can compare two `GenericNode` like this:

```
let f = GenericNode<NSNumber>(data: 53)
g.data.isGreaterThan(f.data) // is false in this case.
```

If you just try to write basic BST stuff, this should be good enough to go.

Comment: This will allow me to create `g`, but not to create another `Node` `g2` and check for things like `g.data < g2.data`.  Your proposed solution lacks the `Comparable` protocol, which to me seems essential for building a BST.

Comment: @pjs no, because `T` conforms to `NSObject`, `T` must has implemented `isEqual` method. Then, let's say if you have another `let f = GenericNode<NSNumber>(data: 42)`, they can be compared by `g.data.isEqual(f.data)`.

Comment: Checking whether two objects are equal is not sufficient to build a binary search tree. You really need to know which is the larger and which is the smaller if they're not equal.

Comment: @pjs Aha! Sorry! But it has `isGreaterThan()` and `isLessThan()` methods.

Comment: I was truly hoping for an "all-Swift" solution.  Perhaps in a future generation of the compiler. Meanwhile, use of the `is...Than()` methods checks out for both `NSNumber` and `NSString` so thanks for a workaround.

Comment: @pjs Me too. It's more likely a compiler bug. I hope it will be fixed soon.